# Running MySQL queries inside a loop

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I want to run multiple mysql queries in a loop. Maybe this the wrong approach but thats why I'm asking.

Example:

A user submits a array of userinput and i want loop through it an perform multiple mysql queries. If I hardcode the ID it works but if I set the ID as a VAR it dosen't. When using a VAR it alway shows a result with the last entry.

Best, Tim

```
        if(isset($_POST['list'])){ 
            $list=$_POST['list']; 
            $list_arr=explode(PHP_EOL, $list);
            $list_arr_len=count($list_arr);

            for ($i=0; $i < $list_arr_len; $i++) { 
            echo $list_arr[$i]."<br>";
            $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT col FROM table where id='$list_arr[$i]'");
            $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_NUM);
            echo $row[0]."<br>";


            }
                mysqli_close($con); 
        }
```

Comment: Instead of looping it though like that, try and use `where id IN(" . implode(',', $list_arr) . " ) ");` also, is your ID a interger or a char?

Comment: thanks so far, my user input is a string. i already thought of using IN but i i have to to more then just fetching from the database so it would be nice to use a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create `PDO` object and set it in exception mode

```
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1';
$user = 'dbuser';
$password = 'dbpass';

try
{
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);    
} 
catch (PDOException $e) 
{
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

You are posting a comma separated list (I'd post an array but what the hell), so we're going to simply parse the string into integers and stick it in MySQL's `IN` clause

```
if(isset($_POST['list']))
{ 
    $list = str_replace(["\r", "\n"], "", $_POST['list']);

    $numbers = strpos($list, ',') !== false ? explode(",", $list) : (int)$list;

    // This can probably bet written nicer, the idea is to have each number explicitly typecast to int so it's safe to stick in a query directly
    // Basically, you want "1,2,3,4,5" without the possibility of having some bad input here
    if(is_array($numbers))
    {
        $numbers = implode(",", array_map(function($number)
                                    {
                                        return (int)$number;
                                    }, $numbers));
    }

    // And the nice, one liner, where you query and fetch the records which are now in the array called $records
    $records = $pdo->query(sprintf("SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE id IN(%s)", $numbers))->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

Note: I didn't test the code so don't copy paste it, it most likely contains errors. I wrote the answer to show how easy it is to use `PDO` and retrieve results easily, in one liner.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i will give this  try. Cheers, Tim

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in one query like this:

```
if(!empty($_POST['list'])){ 
            $list=$_POST['list']; 
            $list_arr=explode(PHP_EOL, $list);
            $list_id=implode("', '", array_map('mysqli_real_escape_string', $list_arr));

            $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT col FROM table where id IN ('{$list_id}')");
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_NUM)) {
            echo $row[0]."<br>";


            }
                mysqli_close($con); 
        }
```

in this example no matter which type of colum for id u use

Comment: ok thanks, i tried but same problem, if I hard code the IN statement no problem if i use a VAR it dose not work.

Comment: Update:

i supplied 
id1 ','id2
as user input and use $list as VAR like :
mysqli_query($con,"SELECT col FROM table where id IN ('$list')");
that works with no problems, so my guess it has somthing to do with \n etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think this shall work:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT col FROM table where id=".mysqli_real_escape_string($list_arr[$i])."");
```

Answer (score 0):

First Create a string of all the ids and use IN(String of Ids) in your query and store all the data corresponding to id in an array.

```
$stringIds = "";
for ($i=0; $i < $list_arr_len; $i++) 
{ 
     if (is_null($stringIds))
     {
          $stringIds = '"' . $list_arr[$i] . '"';
     }
     else
     {
          $stringIds .= ',"' . $list_arr[$i] . '"';
     }
}  

$resulSet = mysqli_query($con, ""SELECT col FROM table where id='?'"");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resulSet))
{
     mainArray[$row['id']] = $row; 
}
```

Now, your able to fetch all your data from the array using foreach loop and please use PDO to avoid SQL Injection.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was:

\n \r

This c0de works for me now ( also IN('') might be the better idea ):

```
if(isset($_POST['list'])){ 
            $list=$_POST['list']; 
            //echo $list;
            $replace = array("\n", "\r");
            $id = str_replace( $replace, ",", $list);
            $id_arr = explode(",", $id);
            $id_arr_len = count($id_arr);

            for ($i=0; $i < $id_arr_len; $i++) { 
                # code...
            $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT col1,col2 FROM table where id='$id_arr[$i]'");

                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                echo $row['col1'].': ';
                echo $row['col2'].'<br/>';
                }

            }

        }
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to pass unsanitized user input to your query?

Comment: Sure you are right but this was not the scope of my question. Since i got this working now i can work on preventing SQL Injections. Plust this will never see the www. It's for internal usage. But of course you are right.

Comment: Are you interested in a solution involving less code, `PDO` and prepared statements? I'll gladly post it unless it's not what you're after.

Comment: sure go ahead, I'm alway interested in learning something new